# Linking native WebRTC application with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, webrtc

So my goal is to build a native WebRTC application using the WebRTC C++ api.

I compiled webrtc for use with Visual Studio (2015) using the following guide:

https://github.com/ipop-project/ipop-project.github.io/wiki/Building-the-WebRTC-lib-for-Windows

After the build completed I tried creating a new Visual Studio console project and added the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define WEBRTC_WIN

#include <webrtc/api/peerconnection.h>
#include <webrtc/api/peerconnectionfactory.h>
#include <webrtc/api/peerconnectioninterface.h>

int main()
{
    auto pcf = webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory();

    std::cout << "Hallo!" << std::endl;
}
```

Adding the build directory to the include search path works fine, however I'm unable to link the application, searching the build directories for lib-files and adding them to the linker only adds more link error as there is a whole bunch and I suspect some of them should not be linked to my application.

What is the correct way to link the application, and how do I know what .lib-files the functionality I use resides in?

Comment: what does the link error say?

Comment: See my comment on Martin Bonner's answer. Linking against _all_ the libraries generated during webrtc build produces the following 27 linker errors: http://pastebin.com/Q9s3X5wA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it!

After digging around in the build files for the examples in WebRTC I found that the following libraries should be linked:

```
obj\webrtc\api\libjingle_peerconnection.lib
obj\webrtc\system_wrappers\field_trial_default.lib
obj\webrtc\system_wrappers\metrics_default.lib
obj\third_party\jsoncpp\jsoncpp.lib
obj\webrtc\media\rtc_media.lib
obj\webrtc\base\rtc_base_approved.lib
obj\webrtc\webrtc_common.lib
obj\webrtc\webrtc.lib
obj\webrtc\system_wrappers\system_wrappers.lib
obj\webrtc\voice_engine\voice_engine.lib
obj\webrtc\common_audio\common_audio.lib
obj\third_party\openmax_dl\dl\openmax_dl.lib
obj\webrtc\common_audio\common_audio_sse2.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\audio_coding_module.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\cng.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\audio_encoder_interface.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\g711.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\pcm16b.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\ilbc.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\webrtc_opus.lib
obj\third_party\opus\opus.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\g722.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\isac.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\audio_decoder_interface.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\isac_common.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\red.lib
obj\webrtc\rtc_event_log.lib
obj\webrtc\rtc_event_log_proto.lib
protobuf_lite.dll.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\neteq.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\builtin_audio_decoder_factory.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\audio_decoder_factory_interface.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\rent_a_codec.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\audio_conference_mixer.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\audio_processing.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\audioproc_debug_proto.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\audio_processing_sse2.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\webrtc_utility.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\media_file.lib
obj\webrtc\base\rtc_task_queue.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\audio_device.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\bitrate_controller.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\paced_sender.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\rtp_rtcp.lib
obj\webrtc\common_video\common_video.lib
libyuv.lib
obj\third_party\libjpeg_turbo\libjpeg.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\remote_bitrate_estimator.lib
obj\webrtc\voice_engine\level_indicator.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\congestion_controller.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\video_capture_module.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\video_processing.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\video_processing_sse2.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\webrtc_video_coding.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\webrtc_h264.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\webrtc_i420.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\video_coding\utility\video_coding_utility.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\video_coding\codecs\vp8\webrtc_vp8.lib
obj\third_party\libvpx\libvpx.lib
obj\third_party\libvpx\libvpx_intrinsics_mmx.lib
obj\third_party\libvpx\libvpx_intrinsics_sse2.lib
obj\third_party\libvpx\libvpx_intrinsics_ssse3.lib
obj\third_party\libvpx\libvpx_intrinsics_sse4_1.lib
obj\third_party\libvpx\libvpx_intrinsics_avx.lib
obj\third_party\libvpx\libvpx_intrinsics_avx2.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\video_coding\codecs\vp9\webrtc_vp9.lib
obj\webrtc\p2p\rtc_p2p.lib
obj\webrtc\base\rtc_base.lib
boringssl.dll.lib
obj\third_party\usrsctp\usrsctplib.lib
obj\webrtc\modules\video_capture_module_internal_impl.lib
obj\third_party\winsdk_samples\directshow_baseclasses.lib
obj\webrtc\pc\rtc_pc.lib
obj\third_party\libsrtp\libsrtp.lib
winmm.lib
dmoguids.lib
wmcodecdspuuid.lib
amstrmid.lib
msdmo.lib
crypt32.lib
iphlpapi.lib
secur32.lib
Strmiids.lib
```

Comment: Feel free to use the `merge_libs.py` script located inside the `src/webrtc/build` directory. It will generate a single webrtc.lib file. I'm also maintaining a collection of build scripts if you are interested: https://github.com/aisouard/libwebrtc

Comment: That is a mess of random dependencies! Which makes things worse because setting `is_component_build=true` seems to have no effect. So basically this will statically link the world. Why would I want audio_confrence_mixer in just any application!

Comment: @dashesy the linker will hopefully strip anything not needed, but yeah, this is messy af. However, the latest WebRTC (M58) seems to build a single webrtc.lib by default now, reducing the link list to it and just a few satellites (like boringssl & protobuf_lite).

Comment: cannot find merge_libs.py.  Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

The document you linked to, says you need the following libraries:

- boringssl.dll.lib
- boringssl_asm.lib
- field_trial_default.lib
- jsoncpp.lib
- rtc_base.lib
- rtc_base_approved.lib
- rtc_p2p.lib
- rtc_xmllite.lib
- rtc_xmpp.lib

I would link against all of them.  It's unlikely to hurt.

Comment: Tried it, it fails to resolve CreatePeerConnectionFactory: Severity Code "LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class rtc::scoped_refptr<class webrtc::PeerConnectionFactoryInterface> __cdecl webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory(void)" (?CreatePeerConnectionFactory@webrtc@@YA?AV?$scoped_refptr@VPeerConnectionFactoryInterface@webrtc@@@rtc@@XZ) referenced in function main WebRTC-TEst C:\dev\WebRTC-TEst\main.obj 1"

Answer (score 0):

There is a precompiled (binary) package available for Windows: [here](https://sourcey.com/precompiled-webrtc-libraries/).
It contains a single lib to link, libwebrtc_full.lib

Comment: is this still supported?  Looks like no changes since 2017?